# File synchronization between two Linux servers

Tags: linux, centos, sync, rsync

We have a two web servers running CentOS. We need to sync images that users uploaded.

No servers should be needed to synchronize those, because we need to handle failover. Also, we need to do a two-way sync.

We tried `rsync` and `inotify`, but both require a server to be set up, so we can't do failover.

How else can we do that?

Comment: Please specify which type of server (operating system) you are using... there are loads fo good tools to do this.  If its windows server based, look into DFS

Comment: Why can't you set up an rsync server on both ends?

Comment: @jorn, can we? would it have an infinitie loop between two?

Comment: Not infinite, when files stop changing, `inotify` should stop notifying. However, I would limit the amount of `rsync` processes.

Comment: It may be easier for you to use a distributed filesystem. Have you looked at HDFS or XtreemFS for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can just run rsync on both servers:

```
server1$ rsync -a -v -e "ssh -c arcfour" user@server2:/path/to/files /path/to/files
server2$ rsync -a -v -e "ssh -c arcfour" user@server1:/path/to/files /path/to/files
```

Rsync will only copy files that are not yet on the destination system.

Comment: so we can also set inotify on both server, it would be ok?

Comment: It may be smart to also use `-u`… It will prevent newer files to be overwritten by an older version.